# Center/Right-justify two labels in GTK sharp

Tags: label, gtk#, right-justified

I have two labels I want to horizontally align within a window, but need one to be centered and the other to be right justified.  How do I accomplish this with boxes and/or tables?

Comment: Hi Dan, not quite sure what you're asking. I assume the Label widget's justify property is no good in this context?

Comment: Apart from the title bar, I wanted a header across the top of my window that displayed a title in the center, and the date/time on the right hand side.  The label justify property might have worked just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating an HBox and added it to a VBox.  To the HBox I added three widgets:

```
var hBox = new HBox(true, 0);
hBox.PackStart(new Label(), true, true, 0);
hBox.PackStart(new Alignment(0.5f, 0, 0, 0) { new Label() }, true, true, 0);
hBox.PackStart(new Alignment(1, 0, 0, 0) { new Label() }, true, true, 0);
```

The key seemed to be homogeneous sizing (the true in the HBox constructor) and the center and right alignment widgets.